# Hide directory subdirectory mobile from URL www.abc.com/mobile/*

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have directory where php files are places . All files can be accessed from www.myurl.com/* . If user access my site from mobile , he automatically redirected to www.myurl.com/mobile/  . I don't want to show mobile directory in url  to users . Suppose if xyz.php file is placed inside main directory and subdirectory , and user open open url www.myurl.com/xyz.php  from mobile device ,  xyz.php file inside subdirectory mobile should be accessed .

If user access mysite.com/mobile from his desktop browser then he should be redirected to mysite.com How can I get desired results using HTACCESS ?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]


RewriteRule ^((.*))$ mobile/$0 [PT,L]